# Classes that don't throw but depend on libraries that do

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote some classes that don't throw exceptions but they use the STL and the STL can throw exceptions. For example in my class there are functions that use std::vector, std::list, std::string. The STL could throw when copying a string or creating a vector, right? So I cannot describe my classes as exception free, right?

What do you guys do in a circumstance like this? Do you wrap every function in a try/catch? How do you describe your class? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid exceptions?

Comment: @AlanStokes If you need reason to avoid exceptions, just compare them to the `goto` statement. If you do this fairly, you will realize that exceptions are far more evil than the `goto`: they can skip unknown amounts of entirely unrelated code while the `goto` is only able to skip code within the same function. The effect of a goto is really extremely local and well controlled compared to an exception. So, if you avoid `goto` (which you should), you should avoid exceptions as well.

Comment: @cmaster You are missing out on one of the best features of C++, I'm afraid.

Comment: @cmaster your reasoning has good points but your conclusion is absurd. How do you explain the fact that modern languages have *removed goto* but *still have exceptions*?

Comment: @djechlin That remains a mystery to me. I can only conclude that people have just not realized. I myself never questioned the validity of the concept of exceptions for many years. You say, my conclusion is absurd because the majority of programmers thinks exceptions are great. But it has happened that the majority was plain wrong, it can happen again. I, for one, will stand by what reason forces me to believe: exceptions are worse than `goto`. So, either `goto` is not harmful, or exceptions are harmful. Which one will you pick?

Comment: Many languages follow all kinds of "that's just how it's done" approaches to design without any critical thinking or deep inspection into the pros and cons of such decisions. Other languages also are just not C++ and what _might_ make sense for Ruby or JavaScript or C# do not magically and automatically make sense for C++. I would have imagined that afterschool specials would have taught people that "everyone else does it, so it must be good" is a terrible way to think, but apparently not. :)

Comment: @cmaster: Exceptions are not intended for skipping code.  They are intended for doing something more useful than the default behavior of `std::abort()` when something uncommon goes wrong.  That useful thing typically needs to be very different from what the code was about to do in the common case, sure.

Comment: @cmaster googling around a bit...  http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/10/14/taking_exception_to_joel_spolsky/ has several links, http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200310.html#e20031013T222251 seems good. Exceptions are here to stay, if you either use `goto` in modern C++ code or don't use exceptions you're going to be in an extreme minority (look at any major commonly used library).

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch see above links. If many smart people disagree with me, I'm more likely wrong than genius, and it would behoove me to spend more time trying to find out why I'm wrong than why I'm right.

Comment: @djechlin: "Exceptions vs error returns" is a false duopoly. Any exception-safe code you've written is either trivial or most likely not actually exception-safe. Not to mention that a number of very useful algorithms and containers are literally impossible to make exception-safe. There are large segments of the C++ community that disable exceptions, avoid the STL, ban new and delete, and use middleware that is exception-free. A lot of smart people definitely disagree with you, so by your own reasoning... :)

Comment: @aschepler True, exceptions are not *intended* for skipping code, *but they do*. With all the negative consequences. And they skip code *in totally unrelated functions*. With all the negative consequences. Like it or not.

Comment: Luckily, I do like it.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, if anything you call from a particular member function (including constructors, implicit calls that the compiler provides for you, etc) can throw an exception, then the member function can throw an exception. So it's not exception free.

As to what to do about it: It really depends on what your code is supposed to do, and "what can you do if it throws an exception". You probably want to catch it SOMEWHERE, but since most likely scenario is either that you've done something daft and/or run out of memory, you will most likely not really be able to do much about the situation. (Of course, if you use for example `std::vector::at()` with an out-of-range value, then it will throw an exception - that's "doing something daft" - likewise the one I've done a couple of times, `const char* p = 0; .... std:string str(p);` - it may of course crash rather than throw an exception, but my compiler seems to throw a bad_something exception from this). Any of these things, if they are not intended, is probably "the death of your code anyway". If you are using `std::vector::at()` with a bad index and you "intended it", then you probably shoul rethink your design - exceptions are "expensive" compared to `if (vec.size() > index) ... else ...`

I'm not sure if there is a specific term for "my class does not throw exceptions, but uses standard library that may do".

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the possibility of STL-classes throwing due to allocation problems is very slight: it is more likely that your process gets shot down by the OOM-killer than that an allocation fails. So I tend to ignore these kinds of exceptions and just let them crash the program. I am quite radical about not using exceptions otherwise, so I don't have any `try{}catch(){}` in the code I write.

When I'm not alone on a project, I don't try to wrap every function call either, I just declare my functions as `throw()`. This has the effect that any unexpected exception coming out of any other function I call will safely crash the program instead of propagating up to some other function that might catch it. That way I can be certain that no vital part of my code is skipped without someone noticing.

Comment: It's absurd to say if you detect a bug (i.e. an unexpected exception) you should crash the *entire* application. For instance if you are writing a logging library it needs to completely assure it will never interfere with the program's behavior, and it's much better to swallow bugs than to fail. This applies to any "mixin" type behavior. E.g. a module doing read-only data tracking and analytics should not crash an entire web application if it fails.

Comment: @djechlin I agree with you that some service provider should not crash the entire application. My preference for crashing noisily and immediately is to *enable debugging*. Any exception that I did not expect when I wrote the code is a bug: I absolutely have to handle it correctly. And crashing allows me to just dump the thing into the debugger and examine the situation. If I just let it pass my code unnoticed, it will likely leave the program in an inconsistent state (because I did not expect it!), and you know how hard it is to debug problems due to corrupted data.

Comment: false - either that exception will be caught in a more general exception block above and properly handled, or it will escape anyway since it's never caught and crash the program anyway. Typically top level mains will have something like, e.g. in Java: `catch(Exception exc) { System.err.println("Exception: " + exc.getMessage()); exc.printStrackTrace(); System.exit(1); }`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to GotW #82 (http://gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm) it is always a bad idead to add exception specifications:

> Exception specifications can cause surprising performance hits, for
>   example if the compiler turns off inlining for functions with
>   exception specifications. A runtime unexpected() error is not always
>   what you want to have happen for the kinds of mistakes that exception
>   specifications are meant to catch. You generally can't write useful
>   exception specifications for function templates anyway because you
>   generally can't tell what the types they operate on might throw.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is flawed.

> I wrote some classes that don't throw exceptions but they use the STL and the STL can throw exceptions.

You need to answer the question - what do you do if your program fails due to an STL failure? Your only options are to throw an exception or return a value. (Or crash the application on the spot.) One option you have of course is to return a custom class you write `SuccessOrFailure`. On success, it will contain the actual return data, and on failure it will contain some information describing what went wrong. In other words, you can jam the exception that would have been thrown into the return value, and force the client code to check the return value for error and do what it would have done if you threw an exception, only writing C-style return value code that was *one of the banes of C programming before exceptions were invented*. But if this is your design decision, it's what you have to do.

Or you could try to return some value that means "failure", e.g., for an integer, return 0 or -1. This solution of course will only work if your actual function clearly only returns positive numbers, and if you use a fixed number it won't reveal any information on the error.

My point is, **you need to figure out how to handle failures whether you're throwing an exception or not.** "Not using exceptions" does not answer the question, it just ignores the work.

The *only* valid reasons not to use exceptions I have seen are

- you are maintaining old return value-oriented code, in which case you need to do the perfunctory work of turning your exceptions into different return codes
- you can handle all of your errors (e.g. a mixin or logging library), in which case you should wrap in try/catch and handle all your errors

Comment: My classes don't throw exceptions because they just don't have to really. If a function fails it fails and returns false. What's confusing for me is if the STL is throwing an exception does that mean my class is throwing an exception... and the answer seems to be yes, so my class is not exception free. If I *don't* make my class exception free and don't wrap all the STL in try/catch then I just won't call it exception free. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @test if I call `isItRainingOut()` and it returns `false`, I expect that it isn't raining, not that the STL function used by `isItRainingOut` threw an exception. If that's not the case for you - e.g. if your operation is actually a `void` operation and you're returning whether it succeeded - then wrap in try/catch and do `catch(exc) { return false; }`. This is C-style, which exceptions replaced.

Comment: @djechlin: I agree that "ignoring exceptions is probably wrong", but I don't agree that "you should use exceptions for everything that can go wrong". It really depends on what you expect to go wrong, and how often. Throwing an exception is typically more "expensive" than returning an error status. So if the purpose of the function is to "check if the file can be opened", then returning a true/false value is the right thing to do. If the purpose is to open a file that you expect to be there, then throwing an exception is a good plan. Overall, it really depends on what the code is meant to do...

Comment: @MatsPetersson if `checkIfFileCanBeOpened` can't tell if the file can be opened - for instance if its IO block was interrupted (I'm thinking in Java here for this example) - then it should throw an exception rather return `false`. If it checks if the file can be opened then it can't be, then the function had no error and succeeded in determining that it can't be, and should return `false`. So yes, it's subtle whether something is an error and the function can't complete or whether it completes with some "unfortunate" result, but I would maintain this can always be reasoned through and decided.

Comment: I was more thinking something like `fileExists()`, for example. And I agree, there is a decision to make, whether you want to throw an exception, return some sort of error code, or call `assert`, `abort` or `terminate` after printing some suitable message - largely depends on what the calling code can be expected to do about it...

Comment: @djechlin The only case I can see where an exception would be thrown in the code is a rare one, if STL push_back or something failed because the program is out of memory. So if `bool foo::isItRainingOut()` does a vector push_back that throws an exception because there's no memory to add a string to the vector then it wouldn't return false, the STL exception would just throw before that happened, correct?

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++, you can use `noexcept`.

```
struct Foo {
  void bar() noexcept(true) {
    some_function_that_throws();
  }
};

void safe_function() {
  // safe as nothing here can ever throw
  Foo* foo = new(std::nothrow) Foo();
  if (foo)
    foo->bar();
  delete foo;
}
```

The caveat here is that the process will exit if an exception is thrown and not caught inside a method with noexcept. This may be considered a good thing by some; it's similar to using an assert. The behavior is ultimately similar to just not worrying about the exceptions as an uncaught exception will normally terminate the process. The main difference is that religously using `noexcept` functions when appropriate can produce faster and leaner code (even in so-called "zero overhead exceptions" ABIs).

In some industries, simply compiling with -fno-exceptions or equivalent is common practice. STL implementations typically support this mode. Some offer some slightly non-standard behavior in order to check for or handle failure in cases such checks are needed. Keep in mind that most STL exceptions originate at some level from out-of-memory conditions and there's rarely much recovery you could do then even with exceptions; simply crashing isn't much different than whatever else is going to happen anyway. There are applications where handling these situations are important, but the overwhelming odds are you're not working on one of these (and if you are, C++ may not be the best choice of language).